# Photoshop Script: exportDocument

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to save my image as a transparent PNG and wrote a script which suddenly stopped working. I get this error message:
[image: Photoshop 11.0.2 error when executing exportDocument]

```
docExportOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb 

docExportOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG //-24 //JPEG, COMPUSERVEGIF, PNG-8, BMP 
docExportOptions.transparency = true 
docExportOptions.blur = 0.0 
docExportOptions.includeProfile = false 
docExportOptions.interlaced = false 
docExportOptions.optimized = true 
docExportOptions.quality = 100 
docExportOptions.PNG8 = false 

docRef.exportDocument (theFile,ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,docExportOptions)
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Or any other solutions to save the docRef as a transparent PNG?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Phew. Solved ^^

The path didn't exist and that error seems to be a standard error. Pretty confusing...

Comment: The path where the image should be saved didn't exist on my machine (I deleted it accidentally). I entered the correct path and the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

The folder path was the problem i copied the folder path from windows explorer
it looks like

> "C:\Users`\Dropbox\android_work\06_Game_tests\car race verti\04
>   testing"

and pasted it in adress bar or the internet broser pressed enter
i got this

> "file:///C:/Users/%60/Dropbox/android_work/06_Game_tests/car%20race%20verti/04%20testing/"

i copied

> "C:/Users/%60/Dropbox/android_work/06_Game_tests/car%20race%20verti/04%20testing/"

and used it for folder path and It just worked