# Photoshop script won't save file with percentage symbol in the name

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, photoshop, photoshop-script

I have this script that I am running via photoshops Scripts Event Manager that looks for files with ".jpg" and then saves them for web and reduces the quality to 70%.

It runs absolutely fine until it hits a file with a percentage in the name eg. Background_(25%).jpg. Is there anyway i can alter this script so that i can reduce the quality of these jpgs as well as the ones i am already hitting?

Thanks

```
var imageFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select the folder with JPGs to process"); 
if (imageFolder != null)  processFolderJPG(imageFolder);

function processFolderJPG(folder) {
var fileList = folder.getFiles()
 for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var file = fileList[i];
  if (file instanceof File && file.name.match(/\.jpg$/i)) {
                open(file);
var docJPG = app.activeDocument;
var strtRulerUnitsJPG = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
var strtTypeUnitsJPG = app.preferences.typeUnits;
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
app.preferences.typeUnits = TypeUnits.PIXELS;
var saveFileJPG = new File(decodeURI(activeDocument.fullName.fsName)); 
saveFileJPG.remove();
SaveForWebJPG(saveFileJPG,70); // set quality to suit
app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = strtRulerUnitsJPG;
app.preferences.typeUnits = strtTypeUnitsJPG;      

  } else 
if (file instanceof Folder) {
       processFolderJPG(file);
     }
   }
}
function SaveForWebJPG(saveFileJPG,jpegQuality) {
var sfwOptionsJPG = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb(); 
   sfwOptionsJPG.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG; 
   sfwOptionsJPG.includeProfile = false; 
   sfwOptionsJPG.interlaced = 0; 
   sfwOptionsJPG.optimized = true; 
   sfwOptionsJPG.quality = jpegQuality;
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFileJPG, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, sfwOptionsJPG);
}
```

EDIT: I need the files to remain the same filename.

Comment: What does it do when it encounters one of these files? Are you getting an error?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. The JPG opens up and everything just stops.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error, supposedly, its reason is somewhere near the `decodeURI` function – `%` symbols usually take place in the beginning of many symbols, like

> Encoded URI: en.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2F95%25_Confidence_interval
>   Decoded URI: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/95%_Confidence_interval

Without any additional information given, I'd try this:
`file.name.replace('%', '').match(/\.jpg$/i))`

p.s. maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796720/replace-symbol-with-word-percent) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664750/photoshop-script-exportdocument?rq=1) questions would be helpful (especially the second one)